# KaTeX accents in LaTeX

Tags: packages

Is there a latex package which defines all the commands supported by KaTeX? I would like to have my .tex documents as compatible as possible with KaTeX.

- These are commands supported by KaTeX:
  https://katex.org/docs/supported.html
- There is also a page with hints to the underlying packages:
  https://github.com/KaTeX/KaTeX/wiki/Package-Emulation

(PS: If the answer is no, I will probably just define it myself. It won't be too difficult for my user case.)

Comment: the first linkk all look like standard latex commands apart from overlinesegment which is in fdsymbol and mdsymbol packages

Comment: They have a few extra things, for example `\Reals` and other commonly used math commands. (Nothing very fancy, but all the things needed for taking quick math notes.)